# Venia storefront setup for Magento 2.3 Ubuntu

Tags: magento2, progressive-web-apps, venia

I am now trying to setup Magento Venia Storefront and connect it to my Magento 2.3. 
I have referred to the following website to do so: https://magento.github.io/pwa-studio/venia-pwa-concept/setup/

1. As of now, I have Magento 2.3 backend setup up and running. I have taken a clone from their official git repository:(https://github.com/magento/pwa-studio.git)
2. I have done a `yarn install` and installed the required packages.
3. After this point, the documentation suggests me to generate an SSL certificate using buildpack for which the command is:
   `yarn buildpack create-custom-origin packages/venia-concept`

Upon doing this, I am now getting the following error:

```
yarn run v1.21.1
$ buildpack create-custom-origin packages/venia-concept
  ⓧ  Missing required environment variables:
     MAGENTO_BACKEND_URL: Connect to an instance of Magento 2.3 by specifying its public domain name. (eg. "https://master-7rqtwti-mfwmkrjfqvbjk.us-4.magentosite.cloud/")
     CHECKOUT_BRAINTREE_TOKEN: Specify a Braintree API token to direct the Venia storefront to communicate with your Braintree instance. You can find this value in Braintree's
     Control Panel under Settings > API Keys > Tokenization Keys. (eg. "sandbox_8yrzsvtm_s2bg8fs563crhqzk")
  ⓧ  Error: Missing required environment variables:
     MAGENTO_BACKEND_URL: Connect to an instance of Magento 2.3 by specifying its public domain name. (eg. "https://master-7rqtwti-mfwmkrjfqvbjk.us-4.magentosite.cloud/")
     CHECKOUT_BRAINTREE_TOKEN: Specify a Braintree API token to direct the Venia storefront to communicate with your Braintree instance. You can find this value in Braintree's
     Control Panel under Settings > API Keys > Tokenization Keys. (eg. "sandbox_8yrzsvtm_s2bg8fs563crhqzk")
  ⓧ  Error: Error: Missing required environment variables:
     MAGENTO_BACKEND_URL: Connect to an instance of Magento 2.3 by specifying its public domain name. (eg. "https://master-7rqtwti-mfwmkrjfqvbjk.us-4.magentosite.cloud/")
     CHECKOUT_BRAINTREE_TOKEN: Specify a Braintree API token to direct the Venia storefront to communicate with your Braintree instance. You can find this value in Braintree's
     Control Panel under Settings > API Keys > Tokenization Keys. (eg. "sandbox_8yrzsvtm_s2bg8fs563crhqzk")
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

As for the first point, I can't find proper documentation as to how to configure Braintree while setting up Venia storefront. And for the second point, I am now running my Magento 2.3 locally and my admin panel only runs on Http.

Any help is appreciated, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First Create your .env file if it is not build with the following command.

MAGENTO_BACKEND_URL="https://magento.local" yarn buildpack create-env-file packages/venia-concept

Now you can find the .env file in the packages/venia-concept/.env where you can set the MAGENTO_BACKEND_URL as your magento url.

If you will go through .env file then you will see that there is a field CHECKOUT_BRAINTREE_TOKEN=token which is commented out. Uncomment it and place the braintree token in it.

For the braintree token create sandbox account at  `https://www.braintreepayments.com/sandbox?_ga=1.114967554.428334232.1579331999` and then copy the token (private key) that you get after the account creating.

Hope It Helps !!